# OpenSSL, reading public RSA key from CString

Tags: c++, openssl, rsa

I'm trying to read an RSA public key from a CString. Before I was doing it from a file and it was simple, I was using:

```
RSA *PEM_read_RSA_PUBKEY(FILE *fp, RSA **x, pem_password_cb *cb, void *u);
```

but now I can't use this method. This is why I thought about using:

```
RSA *PEM_read_bio_RSA_PUBKEY(BIO *bp, RSA **x, pem_password_cb *cb, void *u);
```

But I don't understand the `BIO *bp` argument and how to pass a CString to it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [bio(3)](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/bio.html) documentation

> A BIO is an I/O abstraction, it hides many of the underlying I/O details from an application. If an application uses a BIO for its I/O it can transparently handle SSL connections, unencrypted network connections and file I/O.

And for your case, I would guess [BIO_s_mem(3)](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/BIO_s_mem.html) is the proper type

> A memory BIO is a source/sink BIO which uses memory for its I/O.

and

> BIO *BIO_new_mem_buf(void *buf, int len);
>   ...
>   BIO_new_mem_buf() creates a memory BIO using len bytes of data at buf, if len is -1 then the buf is assumed to be null terminated and its length is determined by strlen. The BIO is set to a read only state and as a result cannot be written to.

So with a C string, I would say this leads to

```
char rsa_key[1024];
...
BIO *bp = BIO_new_mem_buf(rsa_key, -1);
RSA *rsa = PEM_read_bio_RSA_PUBKEY(bp, ...);
```

Comment: Thank u very much, I was having some trouble to really understand how BIO works!

Comment: @darkheir Disclaimer: this is from the docs only. I haven't tried this myself ;-)

Answer (score 0):

A BIO in OpenSSL is similar to a File handle. You use a pair of them to communicate with each other securely like you would with two sockets.

[here a detailed explanation with some example code](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-openssl.html)